# Access is denied when trying to pip install on window - with no admin privileges

Tags: windows, pip, virtual-machine, python-3.7, access-denied

I got the Access is denied error as I am trying to pip install a package.

I would not want to run the command window with escalated privileges as I'm doing the work in a VM which the pip install is triggered by an external build agent without admin provilages. I'm using Python 3.7.5.

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5]

Access is denied: 'c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1.dist-info\entry_points.txt'

Consider using the --user option or check the permissions
```

I wonder if either python.exe or pip.exe is still holding on to entry_point.txt therefore stopping a user with normal privilege changing it?

Comment: That's the full path for site-package: C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages. I would avoid using the --user option as that would install the package to user\AppData\Roaming\Python.

Comment: A standard user cannot modify files in "C:\Program Files (x86)". You need to either install Python for the current user, or use pip in a virtual environment. The virtual environment doesn't have to be 'activated' per se, just as long as you use "python.exe" or "pip.exe" from the virtual environment instead of the system binaries.